# Update androidx SearchView text color in toolbar

Tags: android, menuitem, androidx, searchview

I am having a ton of issues trying to figure out how to change the text on my androidx searchview either via programmatically or within the xml theme.  Below is my relevant code.  How can I update the text from black to white so it shows on a black background like the screenshot?

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/search"
        android:title="Search"
        android:icon="@drawable/search"
        app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
        app:actionViewClass="com.exposure.controls.ExposureSearchView" />
</menu>

public class ExposureSearchView extends SearchView {

    public ExposureSearchView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        //((ImageView) findViewById(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_button)).setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.search));
    }
    
    public boolean isDisabled() {
        return disabled;
    }

    public void setDisabled(boolean disabled) {
        this.disabled = disabled;
    }

    private boolean disabled;
    private MenuItem menuItem;
    private boolean expanded;

    public void storeMenuItem(MenuItem menuItem) {
        this.menuItem = menuItem;
    }
    
    public MenuItem getMenuItem() {
        return this.menuItem;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onActionViewExpanded() {
        super.onActionViewExpanded();
        expanded = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActionViewCollapsed() {
        super.onActionViewCollapsed();
        expanded = false;
    }

    public boolean isExpanded() {
        return expanded;
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a fragment or Activity  you can add the code below on your `onCreateOptionsMenu ()`

```
EditText txtSearch = (searchView.findViewById(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text));
txtSearch.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Comment: I did in multiple places, and no change.

Comment: for me it work on `onCreateOptionsMenu()`method

Comment: That worked, if you can update your answer to that then that will show it was done under that on a fragmen.

Comment: yes now i use it on a fragment but i remember it also worked on the activity!

Comment: Yep I moved it to activity also, so it works there also.

Comment: OK well maybe you have been wrong on the ID but I am thinking about  using the searchView.getchildAt(int in) method to get all the views it contains

Comment: It worked in both the fragment and activity, but I moved it to the activity of the onCreateOptionsMenu.

Comment: So it only works in this method. thanks for your feedback

Answer (score -1):

You should *theme*color ,like

```
?attr/colorOnSurface
```

，it will meet you need.

Comment: No idea what this means.

Comment: Now I don’t have a computer by my side, so I can’t express my meaning well.  But I think my thinking can solve your problem.  Generally speaking, your searchView is in the Toolbar, so you can and should modify the toolbar or its parent.  The way to use the theme.  For example, use android:theme="myTheme.style" in your Toolbar.  In your myTheme file, use <item name="textColor(may be it ,I cannot spell it correctly)">?attr/colorOnSurface</item>